# Как правильно показывать input в View если модель пустая

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Не знаю как правильно показывать input во View.

Делаю форму для добавления менеджеров к компании.

```
  <div class="one field">
        <div class="field">
            <h3 class="ui dividing header">
                Менеджер
            </h3>
        </div>
    </div>

    foreach (var manager in Model.Supplier.Managers)
    {
        <div class="two fields">
            <div class="field">
                <label>ФИО</label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => manager.Name)
            </div>
            <div class="field">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="two fields">
            <div class="field">
                <label>Телефон</label>
                @foreach (var phone in manager.Phones)
                {
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => phone.PhoneNumber)
                }
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <label>Почта</label>
                @foreach (var email in manager.Emails)
                {
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => email.Contact_Email)
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    }
```

Так вот, что логично если нету в модели данных, то вью вообще мне не рисует этот текстбокс. А мне нужно, чтобы рисовало. По идеи это можно сделать с помощью IF /но конструкция будет громоздкая, хотел бы узнать есть ли какой-нибудь изящный способ решить эту задачу?

Comment: [Шаблоны](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/mvc/using-display-templates-and-editor-templates-in-asp.net-mvc.htm)

Comment: Если вы вдруг про циклы для номеров тлф и адресов почты, то озаботьтесь этим вопросом на уровне модели к примеру, и в случае создания нового объекта добавляйте в коллекции по одному пустому объекту `phone` и `email`. Это позволит вам всегда показывать хотя бы один элемент для ввода.

Другие варианты это добавить `if` для проверки пустоты списка и т.п. Но все равно, вы наверное захотите добавлять дополнительные адреса и телефоны, поэтому у вас вероятно будет кнопка "Добавить тлф", которая с помощью JS будет рисовать поля ввода.

Comment: да и вообще несколько странно, что вы вроде добавляете нового менеджера, а в коде у вас выводятся текущие записи менеджеров (то есть цикл).